# i can't select the id nor the class with javascript in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

i want to optimize my header on wordpress, and for that i need to select it with javascript and css, but it acts weird : i can't select it with only its id or its class in css, and not at all in js

in the inspector it appears like that :

```
<header id="site-header" class="transparent-header clr" data-height="61" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/WPHeader">
```

I would expect to be able to select it in css with `#site-header` or `.transparent-header`, but it doesn't work ? However `#site-header.transparent-header` works...

but then i can't figure how to select it in js ? I tried `getElementById("site-header")` and `querySelector("#site-header")` and even `querySelector("#site-header.transparent-header")` (you never know..) without any success

I thought it could be a question of dom not created when the script is run, but it's not working neither in the console

Comment: Did you try ("header#site-header")

Comment: I did now and it didn't work neither